# can an indoor Transfer Switch be used on the other side of the wall as an outdoor service entrance and main panel?

Tags: nec, transfer-switch

Can an indoor Transfer Switch be used on the other side of the wall as an outdoor service entrance and main panel?

The concept is: The outdoor service entrance is wired through the wall to the SE rated indoor transfer switch. Then wired through the wall again from the transfer switch to the outdoor main panel.
Is this ok or will I need a UL listed panel to keep outside

Comment: Why do you want a service entrance transfer switch (whole house transfer) instead of transferring a dedicated standby subpanel?

Comment: I'm considering my options to see what works with my home before purchasing. my inverter is large enough for the whole house.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your inverter setup? Grid-tie inverters can't provide standalone power (due to anti-islanding), and multimode inverters use an internal transfer means instead of an external ATS

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is NO.

An indoor xfer switch enclosure is rated for a dry location only. You would need a Raintight enclosure if you were to use it where it is subject to weather conditions.